# Use interfaces to apply common rules to inherited interfaces

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have some models with the same name in different namespaces such as:

```
A.Request
A.Response
B.Request
B.Response
```

etc

And I have interfaces with common signature:

```
interface IA : Common
{
  A.Response Do(A.Request);
}

interface IB : Common
{
  B.Response Do(B.Request);
}
```

and I want to create a common interface that all interfaces will adhere to:

```
interface ICommon
{
  Response Do(Request);
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work because it will always try to duplicate the methods rather than apply rules on the inherited interface.

I tried using `dynamic`or `object`

```
interface ICommon
{
  dynamic Do(dynamic);
}
```

and I even tried creating a common interface for the models such as:

```
A.Request : IRequest
A.Response : IResponse
B.Request : IRequest
B.Response : IResponse

interface ICommon
{
  IResponse request Do(IRequest);
}
```

But nothing seems to work.

All I want is to have these interfaces with identical signature, implementhing the same method but with models of a different namespace and I can't find a way to do it. 
Perhaps interfaces are not meant to be used to impose common rules on inherited interfaces so I want to find a way to do this.

I want to avoid using generics because already tried it and it doesn't work because the models are sealed and you cannot have a `where IRequest: A.Request`rule.

```
interface ICommon
{
  Tresponse Do<TRequest,TResponse>(TRequest);
}

interface IA
{
 A.Response Do<TRequest,TResponse>(A.Request) where TRequest: A.Request, TResponse: B.Response; <- not allowed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like the following work for you?

```
class ARequest: IRequest {
}

class AResponse: IResponse {
}

interface IRequest {
}

interface IResponse {
}

interface ICommon<TRequest, TResponse> where TRequest: IRequest where TResponse: IResponse
{
  TResponse Do(TRequest request);
}

interface IA: ICommon<ARequest, AResponse>
{
   AResponse Do(ARequest r);
}
```

Or this

```
interface IA: ICommon<IRequest, IResponse>
{
   AResponse Do<IRequest, IResponse>(ARequest r)
       where IRequest: ARequest 
       where IResponse: AResponse;
}
```

Comment: Promising! let me check

Comment: No because the interface has multiple methods. IRequest and IResponse map to classes such as ARequest1, ARequest2, ARequest3 etc all implementing IRequest.

It needs to be done on the method level

Comment: this I had already tried before and it's not allowed because ARequest is a sealed class and compiler complains that it shouldn't be sealed.

Comment: I tried making IA and IB into abstract classes implementing ICommon but then it expects IRequest and if you feed A.Request into the abstract class it still complains even though A.Request implements IRequest :(